How do I fetch the results from a postgresql function?
I am trying to test a Postgres function but I never seem to get any data rows back.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION running_order(ref1 refcursor) 
RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $f$
BEGIN

OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT * from stores;

RETURN NEXT ref1;
END; 
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

And to test it I am running this in pgAdmin 4
 BEGIN;
 SELECT running_order('productslist');--this is
 FETCH ALL IN "productslist";
 COMMIT;

But I never get any data rows back.
Am I doing something wrong here or is pgAdmin 4 unable to deal with the results returned by the function

Here is another example that you should be able to test on any database from pgAdmin SQL query screen.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tablerows(ref1 refcursor)
RETURNS refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
OPEN ref1 FOR
WITH tbl AS
  (SELECT table_schema,
          TABLE_NAME
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE TABLE_NAME not like 'pg_%'
     AND table_schema in ('makespace'))
SELECT table_schema,
       TABLE_NAME,
       (xpath('/row/c/text()', query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as c from %I.%I', table_schema, TABLE_NAME), FALSE, TRUE, '')))[1]::text::int AS rows_n
FROM tbl
ORDER BY rows_n DESC;
RETURN ref1;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

BEGIN;
SELECT tablerows('tablerows');
FETCH ALL FROM "tablerows";
COMMIT;


You're calling the wrong function. The one you showed accepts just the name of the cursor you're supposed to fetch the results from. If the second snipped worked at all, you probably called some other function, not the one from the first snippet. See this example.

Oh my bad, an extra parameter - duh !!

But that doesn't fix the issue - I think many pgAdmin doesn't work properly with running functions because no data is returned but the data columns table is shown

I tested this in pgAdmin4 and it works fine. Make sure you're not selecting something or misplacing the caret when you run things in it or it will run just the selection or wherever statement your cursor is currently in - otherwise you're fine. If you need help debugging the function, post the function with some test data that would let others reproduce the problem.

Why do you even use a cursor? Do you really need it?

@Zegarek - Hmm, strange that in pgAdmin4 I just get an empty results table back with the correct columns but no data rows.  I will take another look.

@Zegarek - I just tested your example in pgAdmin v8.12 and still get no data rows back.

You mean the code that works and does return rows in the demo above, doesn't in your pgAdmin 8.12? Are you sure that's the exact same code?

@Zegarek Yes - see the other example I have just added - which has no dependency on any of my specific data tables

@DuncanGroenewald As long as there is a makespace schema and a table in it, that also seems to work fine: demo.
